# JSON data manipulation and fetching geographic coordinates

Tags: json, mongodb, google-maps-api-3

Scroll to the bottom of the JSON file to find the data structure. Then go back up in the file and look for *position* to find the column labels.

You find the JSON-data here:
[drydo.com/crawler/files/json/data.json](http://drydo.com/crawler/files/json/data.json)

This is how to access the right array to manipulate, this example gets the 9 column, outputting "California":

```
$.getJSON("Infectious Disease_Cases_by_County_Year_and_Sex_2001_2014.json", function(json) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.data[0][9] );
});
```

The thing's that needs to be done is.

1. Getting the long and lat for each city, RESULTING in two new JSON values, "Long" and "Lat".
   Using Google maps API, or similar?
2. Sum all infection cases by *Disease* for *every year 2001-2014*
   divide by the sum of total population for every year. RESULTING in a new JSON value "infection per capita"
3. Finally sum all "infection per capita" by *Disease* for each *County* and divide it by the number of "infection per capita" to get an *county average* for each disease.
   Then divide each "infection per capita" with the *county average*. RESULTING in a new value "Effect size".

Also an effective storage would be in it's place. I've heard that MongoDB could be a good fit for this kind of data.
This is the first time I'm working with JSON, so thoughtful explanation is appreciated.

Thanks

//
Adam

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything, because I know nothing about working with JSON.

- Sum rows and create a new column.

As displayed in bullet point #2.
That would be a good starting point.

Comment: the JSON you posted doesn't appear to be valid. It looks like the problem is in the data section... it should be an array, but the formatting seems to be off. You can paste JSON into something like jsonlint.com to make sure it's valid.

Comment: I tried to reformat the JSON-data but that apparently messed it up.
So now I provided a link to the JSON file instead.