# .getJSON and looping through array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through an multidimensional array, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {


       for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

        var county = json.data[i][9];

        console.log(county[i][9]);
    };

});
```

It work's fine to log one row outside the for loop, simply using:

```
      console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.data[0][9] );
```

Comment: What do you get if you just console.log(country)? Since it's inside your loop you should get multiple logs for [0][9], [1][9] etc. It would really help if you provided a snippet of your response.

Comment: What do you get for `typeof json`?

Comment: "JSON Data: California"

You can find the JSON structure in this other post I made:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127539/json-data-manipulation-and-fetching-geographic-coordinates

Comment: The JSON in your other post isn't valid.

Comment: Okey, it might be that I cut out something important when I was shorting it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that json.length is 0 or undefined, maybee the json is not an array but an object with numbers as his property names like:

`{
  0: {
     9: "property" 
  }
}`

would give you a line in console.log(json.data[0][9]) But its length is undefinded

Comment: Worked! 

I had to put `json.data.length`, not `json.length`.
I didn't think about that the first layer in the JSON object was associative, not just an index.
Also had to change a few things within the for loop:

` for(var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
     
     var data = json.data;
 
     console.log(data[i][9]);
 }; `